# Ajax+XMPP or simple JSON file+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, chat

I wrote a very simple AJAX chat app with jQuery. It simply sends your message to a PHP file via AJAX, then writes that message JSON-encoded into a text file for the receiver to pick up. The JSON file is simple, like {"userid":1,"msg":"hello there"}, and its stored under the receiver's user ID.  Once the receiver detects a timestamp change on the file, it reads the JSON data out of it.

This works well, and it's very fast. But now I'm considering scaling etc, and I am unsure how filesystem-based chat like this would work long-term.  Should I seriously consider an XMPP server and rewrite the Ajax stuff around it, or keep what I have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use XMPP (i.e. every chatter needs an account on some jabber server), why not use an existing solution like https://www.jappix.com/? It's open source and acts like a real jabber client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scalability is your concern, then I would definitely consider [replacing AJAX with XMPP](http://www.dynamicalsoftware.com/ajax/xmpp) even if your app has no chat capability in it at all. Although XMPP has a lot of complexity in it at the protocol level, Strophe does a great job at abstracting away that complexity. Here is some sample code that does the XMPP equivalent to an AJAX call.

```
/**
 * handle the response from the search request
 * @param {Element} retStanza contains the iq result packet
 */
com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.Category.prototype.handleSearchResult = function(retStanza) {
    var a = goog.dom.getElement(com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.appAreaId);
    goog.dom.removeChildren(a);
    var categories = iqresult.getElementsByTagName('category');
    for (i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
    new com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.Category(com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.GuiMode.SEARCHRESULT, categories[i]).render(parentDivTabContent);
    }
}

/**
 * perform a search operation
 * @private
 */
com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.Category.prototype.search = function() {
    var request = $iq({to: 'category@' + com.dynamicalsoftware.opeye.admin.domain, type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'http://www.dynamicalsoftware.com/opeye/admin/category'});
    var outstanza = request.tree();
    connection.sendIQ(outstanza, this.handleSearchResult.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XMPP may be overkill for what you're trying to do. I'd look at some sort of messaging server. For example, with [AMQP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php), you could use:

- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [OpenAMQ](http://www.openamq.org/)
- Any other AMQP 0.8 compatible broker

With [STOMP](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html), you could use:

- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq)
- [Any JMS broker](http://stomp.codehaus.org/StompConnect)
- etc.

Apparently the Zend Framework has something called [Zend_Queue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html) which might also be nice.

See [this question (What is a good message broker for PHP?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655306/what-is-a-good-message-broker-that-works-with-php).

EDIT:

As for why you'd want to do this, XMPP is fairly complicated and large. Something like ActiveMQ + STOMP is much simpler. ActiveMQ is the only one of these I've used so I'll talk about it.

To send a message you'd do something like this (using [PHP Stomp](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html)):

```
<?
require_once("Stomp.php");

$connection = new Stomp("tcp://your-activemq-server:61613");
$connection->connect();
$connection->send("/queue/someOtherUser", "Hey buddy, let's talk.");
$connection->disconnect();
?>
```

Then to pick up messages:

```
<?
require_once("Stomp.php");

$connection = new Stomp("tcp://your-activemq-server:61613");
$connection->connect();
$connection->subscribe("/queue/myQueue");
while(($message = $connection->readFrame()) != null) {
    echo $message->body;
    $connection->ack($message); // Tell the broker that you handled the message
}
$connection->disconnect();
?>
```

Of course, in a real situation you probably want to set a header saying who the message is from before sending it but I'm not sure exactly how you send/receive headers in that library.

An even better option might be to hit [ActiveMQ directly from JavaScript](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html). I suspect security would be hard to implement though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I'm really looking for is not necessarily info on other chat servers, but really whether using the filesystem for storing text files is a bad thing. I've heard this but noone's really confirmed it for me.  One other option is Memcached, but I haven't crossed that bridge yet.

Comment: @Ryan There are a couple reasons a message broker can be better than filesystem storage: Your consumers can be event-based instead of polling (faster, less work for the computer), less IO (although most operating systems cache files in memory), and scaling (you can put message brokers on separate servers). The short version is that a message broker is probably faster.